# Java - why is there an increase in response time over period of time?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm executing a Java program 10,000 times in Eclipse indigo. All operations performed are in memory; no disk IO or network IO. I noticed that over the period of time the response time  increased from 2msec to 25 msec for the same input. Upon plotting the response time, the graph looks linear. First thought was I have not tuned the garbage collector. I have set garbage collector for maximum throughput and less gc pause times. Still no difference.

For screenshots on response time and Java VM GC, [please click the link](http://goo.gl/FTvng)

I'm running Oracle Java on Macbook Pro 2011.

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11M3527)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)
```

Following are my VM settings

```
-server -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -Xms48m -Xmx64m -XX:NewSize=32m -XX:MaxNewSize=32m -Xss2048k -XX:SurvivorRatio=16 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=15 -verbose:gc -Xloggc:gclog.txt -XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

Appreciate it, if any one could shed light on this.

Comment: Could this be at all related to any other processes on your PC that are starving for CPU cycles?

Comment: Thanks Eric for the suggestion. It was an application issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to say what the problem is, based on what you've told us.

- It could be a problem in your application *per se*.
- It could be a problem in the way you are launching your application.
- It could be a problem in the way you are measuring "response time".

---

If you want a better answer you need to explain *how* you are "executing a Java program 10,000 times in Eclipse indigo".

- How / where are the response times being measured?  By Eclipse? By something else?
- Does this really mean that you are running the Eclipse launcher 10,000 times?
- Or are you running some benchmarking framework class that is launching the application?
- Or is it just calling the application's `main` 10,000 times?
- Is Eclipse running the test in a separate JVM or in the Eclipse JVM?

Also:

- When you say there is no network I/O, does that include 127.0.0.x and local IPC?
- What is the application actually doing?  Is it talking to something else in some shape or form?

Comment: Thanks Stephen. The first hint you provided itself solved the issue. It was an application issue. I was modifying a list, which I failed to noticed.

Answer (score 1):

*You* can shed light on it ... by simply profiling your application:

- http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html
- http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/installguide/InstallingGuide.html

Please let us know what you find :)

Comment: I profiled the application using Jprobe and found nothing. The program is a single threaded application executing 10,000 times. Issues related to concurrency should not cause the problem. I have posted the GC performance details at http://goo.gl/FTvng.

Comment: There are several things "profiling" can do for you.  One of them is to identify "hot spots": Which modules are getting called most often? Which modules are taking the longest? Which data structures are those modules using?  Sharing?